# Sidekiq does not boot with proper redis options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I need to run multiple instances of Sidekiq on a machine that is hosting multiple different Rails apps. In order to avoid conflicts, I had one of my apps use a different redis instance, pointed at 127.0.0.1/1 instead of the default 127.0.0.1/0, by using the following code in my `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb`

```
Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { :url => 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1' }
end
```

When I boot my instance of Sidekiq using `bundle exec sidekiq` I get the following boot message:

```
2015-02-04T16:46:59.494Z 15104 TID-ovz94l9m0 INFO: Running in ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
2015-02-04T16:46:59.494Z 15104 TID-ovz94l9m0 INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
2015-02-04T16:46:59.494Z 15104 TID-ovz94l9m0 INFO: Upgrade to Sidekiq Pro for more features and support: http://sidekiq.org/pro
2015-02-04T16:46:59.494Z 15104 TID-ovz94l9m0 INFO: Starting processing, hit Ctrl-C to stop
2015-02-04T16:46:59.541Z 15104 TID-ovz9c4dhk INFO: Booting Sidekiq 3.3.0 with redis options {}
```

The problem is that I want

```
2015-02-04T16:46:59.541Z 15104 TID-ovz9c4dhk INFO: Booting Sidekiq 3.3.0 with redis options {:url => 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1'}
```

instead. What command line options to boot Sidekiq or what config files should I edit to have Sidekiq boot with the redis options reflected in `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb`?

Answer (score 5):

You must set the Redis config in both the `configure_client` and `configure_server` blocks.  You are starting the server.  More info here:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Using-Redis